# bash conda autocomplete on macos

Tags: bash, macos, autocomplete, conda

I would like to enable auto complete for conda commands when I press tab.

I have searched the internet and find some documentation. I have applied the proposed solution, but auto complete is still not working.

[conda.io: enable-tab-completion](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/enable-tab-completion.html)

Is there any other approach. How could I enable autocomplete for conda commands?

Comment: Did you open a new terminal window? On macos, you have to add the `eval` code to `.bash_profile`, IIRC

Comment: yes, I had put eval code to .bash_profile and open a new terminal. It does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Autocompletion is now possible with [conda-bash-completion](https://github.com/tartansandal/conda-bash-completion). Just install it by entering the following in your terminal:

```
conda install -c conda-forge conda-bash-completion
```

The developer provides more thorough instructions on the [project's github page](https://github.com/tartansandal/conda-bash-completion).

Comment: This answer should receive more up-votes :)

Comment: Even I always fall back to my own answer...

Answer (score 2):

**Autocompletion for conda is not supported in bash [right now](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/enable-tab-completion.html#enabling-tab-completion).**

> Conda versions up to 4.3 supports tab completion in bash shells via
>   the argcomplete package. Tab completion is deprecated starting with
>   version 4.4. See issue #415.

It will technically work with versions prior to `4.4`, but I will not recommend using versions so old as major changes were introduced since then, and the development pace of `conda` is quite fast.

Three possible solutions:

- [this issue](https://github.com/conda/conda-docs/issues/635) states completion works for Fish shell, so you might use fish
- the same issue suggests someone could implement autocompletion for Bash...  if you're looking for a project contributing to conda. I believe the [conda team](https://github.com/orgs/conda/people) will gladly point you to the right direction for this.
- there is mention of  [a hack](https://github.com/conda/conda-docs/issues/415#issuecomment-396111267) for Bash, although this is a few months old with no guarantee it will work, and could break at any time

Answer (score -4):

To enable tab completion:

1. Make sure that argcomplete is installed:

   > conda install argcomplete
2. Add the following code to your bash profile:

   > eval "$(register-python-argcomplete conda)"
3. Test it:

   - Open a new terminal window or an Anaconda Prompt.
   - Type: conda ins, and then press the Tab key.
   - The command completes to:

   > conda install

Source:
https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/enable-tab-completion.html

Comment: You fail to cite the first information from this page: `Conda versions up to 4.3 supports tab completion in bash shells via the argcomplete package. Tab completion is deprecated starting with version 4.4. See issue #415.`. This is deprecated.